# Why protect authorization code using PKCE in native apps? What protects access token thereafter?

Tags: oauth-2.0

"The Authorization Code Grant has some security issues, when implemented on native applications. For instance, a malicious attacker can intercept the authorization_code returned by Authorization Server and exchange it for an Access Token (and possibly a Refresh Token)." Ref: [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/authorization-code-pkce)

If I understand the [article](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/authorization-code-pkce) correctly, we go to great lengths to protect the exchange of authorization code and access code in native apps using PKCE.

The premise here is that an attacker "can" actually intercept the authorization code. So we use PKCE to protect it. But **what's stopping** the attacker from intercepting the access token?

**Edit:** Please ignore the following as it seemed to confuse other readers by being ambiguous. 
"What's the point of additional PKCE protection here and what's the point of the 2 step process  (get auth token and then the access token) when there's no back channel."

[New to OAuth2]

Answer (score 6):

**What's the point of additional PKCE protection here and what's the point of the 2 step process (get auth token and then the access token) when there's no back channel.**

What PKCE protects is the front channel authorization code response. Here front channel means the usage of user agent (browser).

When your application runs on a machine (ex:- Mobile phone, desktop or pc), it is not possible to protect embedded secrets. Malicious party can decompile source code and extract embedded passwords. Because of this, OAuth token request cannot be **password protected**.

Adding to this, user agent can be intercepted by any malicious party (think about a browser extension). Thus there is no native protection for authorization response.

To overcome this, PKCE - [RFC7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) provide a mechanism to bind authorization request with token request. In very abstract manner,

1. Generate a secret (in-memory so hard to extract at runtime) at application
2. Hash it and include it in front channel (browser based) authorization request
3. Authorization server will correlate hash value to authorization code sent in authorization response
4. Include secret in token request so authorization server can validate

Now, even when malicious party intercept authorization request, secret is hashed. So they cannot request tokens.! Secret is in-memory which make it difficult to extract.!

Token request occur in back-channel. Which is independent of browser (a direct http call to authorization server). Which is protected compared to browser based connections.

Hope it's clear now

Extra information - Token request can include client id and client secret. Including client secret make things more secure. But as I have highlighted, native applications (pc, mobile sort of apps) cannot have embedded secrets. Thus PKCE add an additional security layer .!

Comment: Thanks. I see how PKCE helps and that was not the intent of the question. The quetion / premise here is that an attacker can intercept the authorization code so we use PKCE. But what's stopping the attacker from intercepting the access token?

Comment: @phani Access token is obtained from a back-channel call. Which stands for a direct http request between application and authorization server. This must work over SSL given it in-transmission protection. Also it is NOT operated over a browser hence no browser based attacks can be deployed. Well indeed attacker can extract access token from program memory, but that will require access to OS and memory level. Which means basically device is already compromised.

Comment: A compromised device can very well be used to obtain user credentials (ex:- Keylogger) which is easier than extracting access token from a running program. Hope this is clear to you ?

Answer (score 1):

The access token is short lived. So if access token happened to be on wrong hands they will not be able to use it for a long time. But if the authorization code is on wrong hands, it can be used to get access token/refresh token for a longer period. Please note that this access token is not for a protected resource of the app but for a protected resource of the user. So the app should try to protect its best to prevent authorization code falling on wrong hands.

With PKCE, the `authorization code` can only be used with `code_challenge` and `code_verifier`([article](http://%20https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce)) So by just using authorization_code attacker can't get an `access token` on behalf of the user as he doesn't process the `code_verifier`

Edit:- The insecurity of authorization flow comes with the fact that there is no way you can protect `client id` and `client secret` in a mobile device. So an attacker can simply steal your app's `client id` and `secret`. But he cannot use just that to access a protected resource of a user without user's consent. An `authorization code` is issued with users consent only. So if that code has fallen to attackers hand attacker has all parameters to use that to get `access_token` and `refresh_token` and access user's protected resources without user knowing. PKCE trying to prevent that type of attacks.

Comment: 1. I think OAuth recommends one-time-use-and-expire for authorization code. So nobody can use an authorization code for "a long time." Ref: Look at the "replay attacks" section at https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/authorization-code-request/

Comment: Hmm, Thanks, I missed that detail. But my intent is the same. if an attacker intercepts the authorization code he could get a refresh token which will be used for a longer period, which is prevented in PKCE.

Comment: If an attacker can intercept authorization code, what's stopping the attacker from intercepting access/refresh token?

Comment: @phanin access/refresh tokens are sent from the authorisation server directly to the client's backend (not the browser). The client would then send these as JWTs in secure cookies back to the browser.

Comment: My last comment isn't 100% accurate. In OIDC, the id token would be used to create a cookie that is sent to the browser, but in oauth, the access/refresh tokens aren't sent to the browser. They're used by the client app's backend to make requests to the authorization server on the user's behalf.